# C -> Valgrind -> Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Tags: c, valgrind, cs50

When i use valgrind i get: Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) on line 37.
Line 37 is where the while loop starts, in the function "check".
I dont know what causes this problem, what it means or how to fix it.
Besides this there are no other problems.

This program is designed to take a dictionary and put it into a hash-table. then a text can be reviewed with the "check" function.

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

int counter = 0;


// TODO: Choose number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 676;

// Hash table
node *table[N];



// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    int hash_value = hash(word);
    node *cursor = table[hash_value];
    while(cursor != NULL)
    {
        if(strcasecmp(cursor->word,word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }
    return false;
}







// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    int hash_0 = 0;
    int hash_1 = 0;
    for (int i = 65; i < 91; i++)
    {
        if (word[0] == i  || word[0] == (i + 32))
        {
            hash_0 = (i - 65);
        }
        if (word[1] == i  || word[1] == (i + 32))
        {
            hash_1 = (i - 65);
        }
    }
    return ((hash_0 * 26) + hash_1);
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // opens the dictionary file
    bool outcome = true;
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (dict == NULL)
    {
        outcome = false;
        fclose(dict);
    }

    // read strings from file
    char woord[LENGTH];
    while (fscanf(dict, "%s", woord) != EOF)
        // put string in node
        {
        node *pointer = malloc(sizeof(node));
        counter++;
        if (pointer == NULL)
        {
            outcome = false;
            fclose(dict);
            break;
        }
        strcpy(pointer -> word, woord);

        // use the hash function
        int hash_value = hash(pointer -> word);

        // insert node into Hash Table
        if (table[hash_value] == NULL)
        {

            table[hash_value] = pointer;
        }
        else
        {
            pointer -> next = table[hash_value];
            table[hash_value] = pointer;
        }
    }
fclose(dict);
return outcome;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    return counter;
}



// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    bool outcome = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        node *cursor = table[i];
        node *destroyer = table[i];
        while(cursor != NULL)
        {
        cursor = cursor -> next;
        free(destroyer);
        destroyer = cursor;
        }

    }
    return outcome;
}
```

Comment: What is `hash`?  What is `table`?  What is `node`?  There's not nearly enough here to see what's going on.  Please update your code with a [mcve].

Comment: What is `table`? Where is it defined, where is it initialised?

Comment: Still not enough.  A [mcve] is a complete program that others can compile and run without any modification so they can see the same problem you see.

Comment: @dbush i will just send the complete program

Comment: Also, are you compiling with a C++ compiler?  Because a C compiler won't accept `node *table[N];` given how `N` is defined.

Comment: I am using a C compiler but i havent had a problem with that so far..

Comment: Note `node *table[N];` is not legal in C. You cannot declare a VLA with static storage duration. Replace N with a preprocessor definition (`const int` does not work in C for this purpose).

Comment: When you insert the first node to a table slot, its `next` pointer remains uninitialised. That's what `valgrind` is tripping over.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. That is a usefull tip, thank you.
Nonetheless I did not manage to fix it without suffering a segmentation fault :(
does anyone have a suggestion for that?

Comment: It isn't clear what you have done, but anyway, that's what the debugger is for.